# JavaScript RangeError: programmatically extract the cause

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I'm getting a RangeError in Node.js, which stack traces as follows:

```
RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
    at new ArrayBuffer (<anonymous>)
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:951:1)
    at createUnsafeBuffer (buffer.js:152:12)
    at allocate (buffer.js:422:10)
    at Function.allocUnsafe (buffer.js:387:10)
    at tryCreateBuffer (fs.js:354:21)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:388:14)
    at parse1 (C:\ml\js\tptp.js:574:20)
    at Object.parse (C:\ml\js\tptp.js:589:2)
```

I want to catch this error. But as I understand it, RangeError is a quite generic exception, and I only want to catch it when it has this particular cause; I don't want to accidentally swallow unrelated errors.

The exception object has no keys, according to `Object.keys(e)`.

Maybe it could be somehow checked for a message equal to "Array buffer allocation failed", but what's the syntax for doing this? Or is there another approach I should be using instead?

Comment: `e.message` seems to give the message. If it's not the correct error, you can re-throw it

Comment: @TrevorKropp Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!